# View MySQL results in a TreeWidget - PyQt4

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pyqt4

iam trying to view a simple MySQL-SELECT in a TreeWidget from PyQt4. Iam able to reach my current Database and iam able to print the results. But i have no idea how it works for me in a TreeWidget.

I found some documentations and tutorials but none of them were really helpful. I hope some of you can help me.

Here is my Code:

```
def SqlConnectionTest(self):


    try:
        cnn = mysql.connector.connect(
              user = 'root',
              host = 'localhost',
              database = 'employeedb')
        self.ui.textBrowser_exceptionDisplay.setText("Connection works!")

        cursor = cnn.cursor() 
        cursor.execute("SELECT * `from employeeinfo_table`;")
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in results:
            print(row)

        #self.ui.treeWidget_EmployeeList.addTopLevelItems()
        if cnn:
            cnn.close()

    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        if e.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            self.ui.textBrowser_exceptionDisplay.setText("Error. Check your username or password!")
        elif e.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            self.ui.textBrowser_exceptionDisplay.setText("Database is not available or does not exist!")
        else:
            self.ui.textBrowser_exceptionDisplay.setText(e)
```

At the moment iam not adding any Items to the treeWidget because i dont know how except this way. This was just testing. It is not looing good i know(Mitarbeiter(DE) = employee(EN)):

```
    item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp1.displayEmployeeName()])
    child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Details"])
    child1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp1.displayFullEmployeeInfo()])
    child2 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Mitarbeiter"])
    child3 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp2.displayEmployeeName()])
    child4 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Details"])
    child5 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp2.displayFullEmployeeInfo()])
    child6 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp3.displayEmployeeName()])
    child7 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Details"])
    child8 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp3.displayFullEmployeeInfo()])
    child9 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Mitarbeiter"])
    child10 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp4.displayEmployeeName()])
    child11 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(["Details"])
    child12 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([emp4.displayFullEmployeeInfo()])


    item.addChild(child)
    child.addChild(child1)
    child.addChild(child2)
    child2.addChild(child3)
    child3.addChild(child4)
    child4.addChild(child5)
    child2.addChild(child6)
    child6.addChild(child7)
    child7.addChild(child8)
    child7.addChild(child9)
    child9.addChild(child10)
    child10.addChild(child11)
    child11.addChild(child12)

    self.ui.treeWidget_EmployeeList.addTopLevelItem(item)
```